# Asyncronous task on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

for reporting reasons I have to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps that will interface an external deployment workflow implemented on another tool.

The tool offers a REST API that allows triggering some action on the external tool and the Azure DevOps pipeline may therefore drive some actions like starting the deployment process of the external tool.

Fact is that those actions are performed asynchronously and are not garanteed to be completed within any given period; I cannot trigger an action and keep polling the triggered action in order to check completion as this exposes to a timeout task failure loosing the alignment between recorded status in Azure DevOps and actual status in the external tool.

Is there a way to tell the pipeline to define checkpoints where the pipeline should wait for an external event, maybe a completion event triggered by the external tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [How to make an Azure DevOps Pipeline wait for an external process to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861360/how-to-make-an-azure-devops-pipeline-wait-for-an-external-process-to-complete)